# Preprocessor Directives in .Net Core for multiple frameworks

Tags: .net, c-preprocessor

I am trying to port several libraries from .NET Framework 4.0 to .NET Core, and saw that one of the useful things you can do is add things like the following that will conditionally compile portions of your code:

```
#if NETCOREAPP1_0
    do something
#elif NET40
    do something else
#endif
```

My question is what to put in place of the `NET40` in the code above. I have only been able to get `NETCOREAPP1_0` and `NETSTANDARD1_6` to be recognized. Every other thing I've put in for the `NET40` hasn't worked, including `net40`, `NET40`, `NET4_0`, and a few others. Is there a list somewhere that would give guidance on how to reference it? Or is there additional steps I need to take in another portion of the project to get it to recognize `net40`?

Comment: You can define your own in project.json, https://blog.lextudio.com/2016/06/port-snmp-from-net-core-rc1-to-rc2/ This blog post has an example.

Comment: This is well-documented in [Developing Libraries with Cross Platform Tools](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/master/docs/core/tutorials/libraries.md).

Answer (score 1):

Try using DNX40. Something along the lines of

> #if NETCOREAPP1_0
>   do something
>   #elif DNX40
>   do something else
>   #endif

This is taken from asp.net though, from this video: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/dotnetConf/2015/ASPNET-5-Deep-Dive around the 36 minute mark. Usually the .net stuff works for the full framework.